# Суммировать значения столбца, смещая с заданным шагом диапазон суммирования

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Стоит следующая задача:

в столбце A записано несколько тысяч чисел. Необходимо в столбце B в каждую ячейку вписать сумму из десяти ячеек столбца А, т.е.

```
B1 = СУММ(A1:A10)
B2 = СУММ(A11:A20)
B3 = СУММ(A21:A30)
```

и т.д.

подскажите можно ли это сделать формулой в самой таблице, а не макросом?

Comment: Я бы смотрел в сторону `OFFSET (СМЕЩ)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=СУММ(СМЕЩ($A$1:$A$10;(СТРОКА(A1)-1)*10;))
```

Но не советую. `СМЕЩ` - функция летучая (пересчитывается при любом изменении на листе). Это сказывается на производительности, часто наличие формул с летучими функциями вызывает торможение, иногда подвисание на длительное время.

Лучше немного длиннее, но без таких возможных неприятностей:

```
    =СУММ(ИНДЕКС(A:A;(СТРОКА(A1)-1)*10+1):ИНДЕКС(A:A;СТРОКА(A1)*10))
```

Первая `ИНДЕКС` определяет начало диапазона, вторая - его конец.

Справедливости ради нужно уточнить, что формулы с динамическим определением диапазонов тоже пересчитываются, но только при открытии книги (здесь разговор о пересчете, не зависящем от входых данных).

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте данную формулу в ячейку `B1` и сделайте автозаполнение (двойной клик на правом нижнем углу ячейки). Под конец будет много ячеек с нулями из-за того что автозаполнение вставит данную формулу до конца значений столбца A.

> =СУММ(СМЕЩ($A$1; (СТРОКА() - 1) * 10; 0; 10; 1))

Comment: Значит, правильнее не автозаполнением, а протягиванием формулы на нужный диапазон.